# Get "Value" from simple JSON using "Key" as variable Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have defined a simple JSON

```
{
  "12345": "Numbers",
  "AAAAA": "AllAs",
  "ABCXYZ": "AtoZ"
}
```

All I want to extract the value of "Key" when passed as a variable. I have tried `body('Parse_JSON')['name']` but its failing.

I just want to get the value of what ever Key I am looking for as variable.[image]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for you want to get the Key value of ABCXYZ which is defined in Variable or do you want to get the Value of ABCXYZ which you have defined in Compose input?

Comment: I want to get the value of "ABCXYZ" which is "AtoZ". ABCXYZ is stored in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it !

`body('parse_JSON')?[variables('name')]`

The above does the following:

1- `body('parse_JSON')` gets the body of Parsed JSON

2- `?[variables('name')]`gets the value of `name` which is equal to `ABCXYZ`

3- Returns `AtoZ`

Answer (score 1):

For those also just starting with logic apps - if its not immediately apparent;

At "Initialize Variable 2" you need to use the "Expression" tab to input the line

`body('parse_JSON')?[variables('name')]`

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment as you are initializing `ABCXYZ` value and that you have already declared in inputs you can just type `ABCXYZ` in value rather than calling `Name` variable

[image]

Comment: The value of "Key" is going to be string in a variable passed in eg. ```var = "ABCXYZ"``` now I need the corresponding value "ABCXYZ". Whatever is the value of var , I need the value of that keypair.

Comment: e.g. Give me the value of key which is passed as a variable. var="ABCXYZ" so I am looking for "AtoZ" in response. The var could be anything.

Comment: Are you looking to initialize the Variable name with the key value of ABCXYZ which is nothing but name=AtoZ https://i.imgur.com/UiaGItR.png

Comment: Imagine this variable is getting a value from some other resource which I will be using to find the matching Key/Value pair from my JSON. I tried ```Body('Parse_JSON')?['name']``` but still didn't work.

Comment: Figured it ! Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add something here as I was looking for a way to use a dynamics value passed in to then use that to look up in a json body to translate that value to a different.

Mapping value eg. {"male":"M", "female":"F", "Non-Specific":"O"}

So I receive the value "Male" but I need that to return as M

to achieve this in a logic app the above partially gets you there.

```
body('Parse_JSON_gender_mapping')?[string(variables('received_gender'))]
```

I had to wrap my use of the variable for the value we received in string() function, even though the value was a string.